# How to display a label having text with line breaks?

Tags: html, css, label, line-breaks

I put text in a `<textarea>` like this:

```
First day
1-one apple.
2-one orange.
3-two cups of milk.
```

But it shows in a `<label>` like this:

```
First day 1- one apple. 2-one orange. 3- two cups of milks.
```

How do I make it look the same as in a `<textarea>`?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Give the label `white-space: pre-wrap` and it will break line as the text area does

```css
textarea {
  height: 70px;
}
label {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

```html
<textarea>
  First day
1-one apple.
2-one orange.
3-two cups of milk.
</textarea>

<br><br>

<label>
  First day
1-one apple.
2-one orange.
3-two cups of milk.
</label>
```

---

Besides the `white-space` property combined with a new line character (e.g. `\n`), the HTML way to break line is using `<br>`, add here is a small sample how they work and differ.

*Note, even space's are preserved using e.g. `white-space: pre`, as seen in the "inline" code sample*

```js
var sample_script = document.querySelector('.sample.script');

var name = "One Two Three";
var name1 = name.replace(/ /g, '\n');
var name2 = name.replace(/ /g, '<br>');

sample_script.innerHTML += name1;
sample_script.innerHTML += "<br><br>";
sample_script.innerHTML += name2;
```

```css
div.pre {
  white-space: pre;
}


/*  styling for this demo  */
body {display: flex;}
.sample {flex: 1; margin: 0 20px;}
```

```html
<div class="sample inline">

  Inline
  <hr>
  <div>
    One
    Two
    Three
  </div>

  <div class="pre">
    One
    Two
    Three
  </div>
</div>

<div class="sample script">
  Script
  <hr>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no way of adding HTML tags in a `<textarea>` tag, so formatting with css for example or using `<br>` tags is not going to work.

Now, `<textarea rows="4" cols="20">`, is let's say the best you can do: you define the minimum rows to be show as "4" and the minimum amount of characters per row: "20".

The best method though is using `<div contenteditable="true"></div>` in which you can use tags like `<br>` and also css styling.

Answer (score 1):

If you are fetching text from textarea itself then when we hit enter in textarea that creates new line return. You can replace that newline return with

`/n, /r with  <br>`

Answer (score 0):

I've found that though html tags such as `<br\>` won't work, UTF-8 punctuation does work. For a line return it would be an "en" space, followed by an "em" space (`&ensp;&emsp;`).

More on UTF-8 punctuation, where you can find the "en" and "em" space:
  https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_utf_punctuation.asp

For me the entity symbol worked, but not the dec or hex, as given in the "try it" example.

Answer (score 0):

For label contents with line breaks, try this simple solution which uses `<span>` and `<br>` tags within the label tag:

```html
<label>
  <span>First day</span><br>
  <span>1-one apple.</span><br>
  <span>2-one orange.</span><br>
  <span>3-two cups of milk.</span>
</label>
```