# How to trim and replace string in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a single string with spaces. Like "Dmitry Vladimirovich Nikitin". My task is to trim a string and replace all spaces with '\n'.

So, as a result I will get:

Dmitry \n
Vladimirovich \n
Nikitin \n

```
var FIO = nameEmployer

console.log(nameEmployer.trim())

FIO = FIO.trim()

FIO = FIO.replace(/ /g, '\n')
```

As you see, I used '/ /g' expression here to replace all the spaces with '\n'.

But 1 single string (Dmitry Vladi Nikitin) appeared.

[image]

What's the problem?

Comment: If that is displayed in an HTML element, the `\n` should be `<br>`

Comment: \n is OK in JS.

Comment: \n is ok in an alert. But not in HTML

Comment: its not HTML. its TypeScript

Comment: *"What's the problem?"* -- there are a lot of problems. A picture is worth one thousand words but on [so] it is usually worth a down vote when it is not required to understand the problem. The picture you posted is completely useless. You probably use the string(s) in HTML and no matter how many spaces or newlines you put inside or around them, they are displayed the same way in the browser. HTML doesn't care about your padding spaces either. Use `console.log()` to check the output of your replacement and post that output as text if something doesn't work.

Comment: @DmitryNikitin You also might want to change your question title, as you actually ask why the text doesn't break line.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Line break in html with \`\n\`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39325414/line-break-in-html-with-n)

Comment: One more possible duplicate [How to display a label having text with line breaks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36558282/how-to-display-a-label-having-text-with-line-breaks/36558525#36558525)

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to find all spaces and replace it with new line character. Regular expression inside replace function is missing \s for space. Below code snippet is working perfectly for me.

```
var FIO = nameEmployer
console.log(nameEmployer.trim())
FIO = FIO.trim()
FIO = FIO.replace(/\s/g, '\n')
```

Answer (score -1):

```html
nameEmployer = nameEmployer.trim()
nameEmployer = nameEmployer.replace(/ /g, '\n')
```

Comment: Clarifications should be in your question, not as an answer.